# Change O365 script to change job title with user prompts for input?

Tags: powershell, email, office365

I have made a script to change an office 365 user's job title.However I want it so there are two user prompt boxes asking for the email address entry and then new job title entry, rather than me changing the users email and title every time.

```
$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the users email address'
$job = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the new Job Title'
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user  -Title $job
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what errors are you getting?

Comment: so its working but its slower than expected to update see update code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always when using user input, either from a `Read-Host` command or by using an inputbox, you should **NEVER** rely on it to be correct.

Always put in some kind of check on user input like:

```
while ($true) {
    Clear-Host
    $upn = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the users UserPrincipalName. Type Q to quit.'
    if ($upn -eq 'Q') {break}

    # test if we can find a user with the entered UserPrincipalName
    $user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn
    if ($user) {
        $job = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the new Job Title'
        Write-Host "Updating title for user $($user.DisplayName) from '$($user.Title)' to '$job'"
        $user | Set-MsolUser -Title $job
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User with UserPrincipleName $upn not found. Please try again."
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not too difficult!

Here's a small helper function you can use to make the worlds most basic text input GUI in PowerShell, with params to customize the title and the message shown to the user.

```
Function Get-TextInput {
Param($Description='Please enter the information in the space below:',$Title="Data Entry Form")
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = $Title
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = 'OK'
    $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
    $CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
    $form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
    $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
    $label.Text = $Description
    $form.Controls.Add($label)

    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)

    $form.Topmost = $true

    $form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
    $result = $form.ShowDialog()

    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
        $x = $textBox.Text
        $x
    }
}
```

Gives you a UI like this:

[image]

Here's how you'd use it:

```
#Include the whole function in the body of the script here
$UserPrincipleName = Get-TextInput -Description "Enter User Name" -Title "MSOL Script"
$UserTitle = Get-TextInput -Description "Enter Title For this position" -Title "MSOL Script"
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipleName -Title $UserTitle
```

If you want to know how this is made, check out one of these two sources:

- [Microsoft Source for the adapted code sample above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-6)
- [My own blog series covering how to make UIs and show them in PowerShell](https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/)